# ForOf loop does not wait for async await call

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want that my loop waits for the two async calls `performAction` and `checkAssertion` before starting evaluating a new `performAction` continuing its loop. I read I should use the for-of loop, but from the logs I've something like this:

```
1. action which violates the assertion
2. action from another bot
3. found and assertion violated during checkAssertion
4. found and assertion violated during checkAssertion
```

How can I force my for-loop to wait?

```
   public async start(duration: number) : Promise<void> {

    // init
    await this.updateStatus();

    // for each round, let bots perform actions
    let bots = this._bots;
    for (let currentStep = 0; currentStep < duration; currentStep++){

        Logger.info({"label": "step", "stepNumber": currentStep});
        console.log("Step: " + currentStep);

        for (const bot of bots) {
            try {
                let transactionResult = await bot.performAction();
                await this.checkAssertion(transactionResult);
            } catch (error) {
                let err = (error as Error);
                // handle error here
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
protected async checkAssertion(transactionResult: any) : Promise<void> {
    if (transactionResult != null) {
        this.checkTotalBalance().then(result => {
            assert(result,  "Total balance not equal to totalSupply");
            assert(!this.checkSuccessfulOverflow(transactionResult), "Successful transaction execution with overflow");
        }).catch( async (error) => {
            Logger.info({"label": "assertionFail", "error": error});
            await this.updateStatus();
            throw error;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure that those functions return the correct promises?

Comment: @Bergi I think yes, both are declared as `async`; `performAction` returns a `Promise<TransactionResult>` and `checkAssertion` doesn't return anything, so `Promise<void>`. Maybe I did some mess with this last one (I edited the code above adding the code of the function). I'm still learning with the Promise/async-await. :)

Comment: Well yes, you forgot to `return` anything :-) Also If you want to use `async`/`await`, I'd recommend not to use `then`

Comment: Sorry, so Do I need to add an empty `return` statement at the end of the function?

Comment: @Bergi I think when you're using async function you shouldn't return explicitly a Promise object, it returned automatic - no?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sure thing, a promise that is automatically resolved with the value that you `return` after having `await`ed everything you depend on. But if you don't `await` anything and don't `return` anything, it means you just get back a promise that is immediately fulfilled with `undefined`, and your promise calls are getting ignored.

Comment: @e.etnann No, you need to `return` the promise chain (`this.checkTotalBalance().then(…).catch(…)`) so that the result of that chain can get awaited.

Comment: Ok, I tried several times and it seems to be working! :) thank you all for your help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're using `then(...)` and `catch(...)` inside the function `checkAssertion` (instead of `try ... catch`). So, it do its action **after** all `performAction()` calls completed. So, rewrite this function as follows:

```
protected async checkAssertion(transactionResult: any) : Promise<void> {
  if (transactionResult != null) {
    try {
      const result = await this.checkTotalBalance();
      assert(result, "Total balance not equal to totalSupply");
      assert(!this.checkSuccessfulOverflow(transactionResult), "Successful transaction execution with overflow");
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.info({ "label": "assertionFail", "error": error });
      await this.updateStatus();
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```